# Binary tree traversing function replies on Steps, so can't run it more than once?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

I implemented a Binary tree in-order traverse function. Essentially there are 3 recursive steps: go the left child, get the cargo data, go the right child. So I designed a incremental flags(a property belong to Node class) to record if the steps on a particular node have been taken during the traverse. The flags runs well if I run it once. When run it the 2nd time, the flags work against the purpose.

Solution: I could have a similar function as the one I use to generate the node objects to reset the flags. But it seems very redundant and repeating my self. Could you provide me a better solution to reset the flags for traversing purpose or a different solution not using the steps at all?

Thank you!
Below is the implementation in Python:

```
"""implementation of Binary Tree"""


class BinaryTreeNode(object):

    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None, parent=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.parent = parent
        self.traversal_step = int(0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_left(self):
        return self.left

    def get_right(self):
        return self.right

    def get_parent(self):
        return self.parent

    def set_left(self, left):
        self.left = left

    def set_right(self, right):
        self.right = right

    def set_parent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def set_traversal_step(self, reset=False):
        if reset == False:
            self.traversal_step += 1

        else:
            self.traversal_step = 0

    def get_traversal_step(self):
        return self.traversal_step


class BinaryTree(object):
    """implement a binary tree
    Protocol:
    any data has value less than value of its parent node
    will be placed on the left child node. While the ones
    greater, will be placed to the right child node
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.tree_depth = int(0)
        self.node_sum = int(0)

    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = BinaryTreeNode(data)
        current_node = self.root
        # print('begin inserting : ' + str(data))
        if self.root:
            # Determine left/right side should be chosen for the new node
            fulfill_status = False
            while not fulfill_status:
                if data >= current_node.get_data():

                    if current_node.get_right():
                          # print('move to RIGHT, and dive to next level')
                        current_node = current_node.get_right()
                    else:
                        current_node.right = new_node
                        new_node.set_parent(current_node)
                        fulfill_status = True
                else:
                    if current_node.get_left():
                          # print('move to LEFT, and dive to next level')
                        current_node = current_node.get_left()
                    else:  # empty node slot found
                        current_node.left = new_node
                        new_node.set_parent(current_node)
                        fulfill_status = True
                # 3. verify status on the current node
                  # print('Current parent node = ' + str(current_node.get_data()))
                  # print('Child status: '
                  #     + 'left=' + str(current_node.get_left())
                  #     + ' right=' + str(current_node.get_right()))
                  # print('new child\'s parent node is:' + str(new_node.get_parent()))

        else:
            # print('Building a new tree now, root = ' + str(data))
            self.root = new_node

        # print('Finishing inserting...' + '#' * 30)

    def query(self, data):
        """check if the data presents in the Tree already"""
        current_node = self.root
        print('begin querying data : {} '.format(data) + '#' * 50)
        if self.root:
            # Determine left/right side should be chosen for the new node
            found_status = False
            while not found_status:
                if data == current_node.get_data():
                    found_status = True
                    break
                elif data > current_node.get_data():
                    if current_node.get_right():
                        # print('move to RIGHT, and dive to next level')
                        current_node = current_node.get_right()
                    else:
                        break  # no existing node larger than the current node.
                else:
                    if current_node.get_left():
                        # print('move to LEFT, and dive to next level')
                        current_node = current_node.get_left()
                    else:
                        break

            if found_status:
                print("The data entry: {} found ".format(str(data)) + '#' * 30)
                # print('my parent node is '+ str(current_node.get_parent()))
            else:
                print("Attention! The data entry: {} is not found ".format(str(data)) + '#' * 30 + '\n')
            return found_status
        else:
            print("Attention! The data entry: {} is not found because the tree doesn't exist ".format(str(data))
                  + '#' * 30 + '\n' )
            return False

    def delete(self, data):
        """there are 3 possible scenarios:
        1. the node has no child
            delete the node and mark its parent node that 'node.next = None'
        2. the node has 1 child.
            delete the node and re-connect its parent node with its child node
        3. the node has 2 children
            find the Smallest key in the node's Right sub-tree
            replace the node with the Smallest key
        """
        current_node = self.root
        print('begin deleting data : {} '.format(data) + '#' * 50)
        if self.root:
            # Determine left/right side should be chosen for the new node
            found_status = False
            while not found_status:
                if data == current_node.get_data():
                    parent_node_data = current_node.get_parent().get_data()
                    print('Parent Node is ' + str(parent_node_data))
                    current_node = current_node.get_parent()
                    if data >= parent_node_data:
                        current_node.set_right(None)
                        print ('removing RIGHT')
                    else:
                        current_node.set_left(None)
                        print('removing LEFT')
                    found_status = True
                    break
                elif data > current_node.get_data():
                    if current_node.get_right():
                        # print('move to RIGHT, and dive to next level')
                        current_node = current_node.get_right()
                    else:
                        break  # no existing node larger than the current node.
                else:
                    if current_node.get_left():
                        # print('move to LEFT, and dive to next level')
                        current_node = current_node.get_left()
                    else:
                        break

            if found_status:
                print("The data entry: {} found and deleted ".format(str(data)) + '#' * 30)
                # print('my parent node is ' + str(current_node.get_parent()))
            else:
                print("Attention! The data entry: {} is not found ".format(str(data)) + '#' * 30 + '\n')
            return found_status
        else:
            print("Attention! The data entry: {} is not found because the tree doesn't exist ".format(str(data))
                  + '#' * 30 + '\n')
            return False

    def traverse_inOrder(self):
        """Steps:
        1 Go Left
        2 Process current node
        3 Go right
        """
        print('traversing tree(in-order)')
        tree_node = self.root
        result = []
        while not (tree_node == self.root and self.root.get_traversal_step() > 1) :
            if tree_node.get_traversal_step() < 3:
                print('\ncurrent node is {}'.format(tree_node.get_data()))
                print('steps: ' + str(tree_node.get_traversal_step()))
                print('Left child is: ' + str(tree_node.get_left()))  # for debugging
                # step1
                if tree_node.get_left():
                    tree_node.set_traversal_step()
                    while tree_node.get_left() and tree_node.get_left().get_traversal_step() < 3:
                        print('traversing to LEFT child')
                        tree_node = tree_node.get_left()
                        tree_node.set_traversal_step()
                else:
                      print('attempted to go LEFT but failed')
                      tree_node.set_traversal_step()

                # step2
                print('getting node data:' + str(tree_node.get_data()))
                result.append(tree_node.get_data())
                tree_node.set_traversal_step()

                #step3
                if tree_node.get_right():
                    print('traversing to RIGHT child')
                    tree_node.set_traversal_step()
                    tree_node = tree_node.get_right()
                else:
                    print('attempted to go RIGHT but failed')
                    tree_node.set_traversal_step()
            # step4 fall back to parent node
            else:
                if tree_node != self.root:
                    print('reversing to parent node {}'.format(tree_node.get_parent().get_data()))
                    tree_node = tree_node.get_parent()
        # step-final: reset all the step markers for the next traverse run.
        print(result)
        return result


    def traverse_preorder(self):
        level_result = []
        result = {}
        node = self.root
        if node:
            pass
        else:
            print('tree does not exist')
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    INPUT_LIST = [50, 76, 21, 4, 32, 64, 15, 52, 14, 100, 83, 80, 2, 3, 70, 87]
    b = BinaryTree()
    for i in INPUT_LIST:
        b.insert(i)
    # print('Query match result : ' + str(b.query(87)))
    b.traverse_inOrder()
    b.query(3)
    b.delete(3)
    b.query(3)
    b.query(80)
    b.traverse_inOrder()
    b.traverse_inOrder()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making things much more complicated than necessary. You can use the execution frame of a recursive function to keep track of which nodes are doing what:

```
def in_order_traversal(node):
    if node is None:
        return
    in_order_traversal(node.left)
    # do whatever you want to do on the current node here e.g.:
    print(node.data)
    in_order_traversal(node.right)
```

If you don't want to use recursion, you can turn the same algorithm into an iterative version by using a stack. Here's a version that uses a `list` as a stack to keep track of the parent nodes who's left children we have visited, but who have yet to be processed themselves:

```
def in_order_traversal_iterative(node):
    stack = []
    while node is not None or stack:
        while node is not None:
            stack.append(node)
            node = node.left
        node = stack.pop()
        print(node.data)  # process node
        node = node.right
```

Neither of these implementations require modifying the nodes, so you can run them as many times as you want and they'll work.

Note that in my example code, I'm not using the `get_X` or `set_Y` methods of your nodes. Accessor methods are not usually need in Python, and public attributes are much nicer. The main reason getters and setters are used in other languages (like C++ and Java) is to allow you the opportunity to add validation or change the internal implementation of the attribute without breaking the class's public API. In Python, if you want to add validation or change the implementation of a public attribute, you can use a `property` to turn the attribute lookup into a method call.